# Selección tipo de tabla en función de un select

Tags: html, table

Hola estoy intentando mostrar resultados de una base de datos con 2 tablas a través de un select.. Mi problema es que los campos de una tabla no son iguales a los de la otra tabla. Cuando intento mostrar los resultados me creo en HTML en una estructura de tabla con unas columnas que funcionan bien para una de las tablas pero no para la otra ya que los campos son distintos. Lo que me gustaría saber es cómo puedo conseguir que en función del valor del select me dibuje la estructura de columnas que preciso para cada tabla.

Comment: Hola, haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).